# Eslint and stylelint setup in VS Code

Tags: visual-studio-code, eslint, stylelint

How to setup eslint and stylelint to have errors displayed inside VS Code editor, when we have that kind of structure of the project:

```
front/node_modules
front/.eslintrc.json
front/.stylelintrc.json
front/js/
front/scss/
backend/js/
backend/scss/
```

Currently errors are only displayed in files from "front" folder. What else I need to configure to be able to see errors inside the VS Code editor while I'm editing files from "backend" folder?

Answer (score 0):

You should move your `.eslintrc.json` and `.stylelintrc.json` configuration files to the root of your project if you're linting the JavaScript and CSS in both the `frontend` and `backend` folders.

Comment: I cannot move it because I extends some configs, like "airbnb" that are installed in node_modules. Node_modules should only be in "frontend" folder.